# extract nth value in nested list with map_dbl

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

I'm trying to extract the nth value from a nested lists in a tibble. I'm trying to do this in the tidyverse.

my raw data is like this

```
> x %>% 
+   select( ., 
+           meta_event, 
+           meta_aktivitet, 
+           meta_subject_id, 
+           time, 
+           time_cum, 
+           vo2) -> 
+ x
> dput(head(x))
structure(list(meta_event = c("001", "001", "001", "001", "001", 
"001"), meta_aktivitet = c("001", "001", "001", "001", "001", 
"001"), meta_subject_id = c("100001", "100001", "100001", "100001", 
"100001", "100001"), time = c("0:10 min", "0:15 min", "0:20 min", 
"0:25 min", "0:30 min", "0:35 min"), time_cum = c(10, 15, 20, 
25, 30, 35), vo2 = c(1.665, 2.515, 2.641, 2.677, 2.66, 2.712)), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

and nested

```
> x %>% 
+   group_by( ., 
+             meta_event, 
+             meta_aktivitet, 
+             meta_subject_id) %>% 
+   nest() -> 
+ x_n
> head(x_n)
# A tibble: 6 x 4
  meta_event meta_aktivitet meta_subject_id data      
  <chr>      <chr>          <chr>           <list>    
1 001        001            100001          <tibble [~
2 001        001            100002          <tibble [~
3 001        001            100003          <tibble [~
4 001        001            100004          <tibble [~
5 001        001            100005          <tibble [~
6 001        001            100006          <tibble [~
```

Here I try to extract some information, through mutate and map_dbl. I've tried different approsses without anyluck.

```
> x_n %>%
+   mutate( vald_end = data %>% map_dbl( ., function(x) max(x$time_cum)),
+           h1 = vald_end - 15*60,
+           index_1 = data %>% map_dbl( ., function(x) which.max(x$time_cum > h1)),
+           index_2 = index_1 - 1,
+           vald_start = map_dbl( data, ~ nth( "time_cum", 
+                                              n = index_1, 
+                                              order_by = "time_cum"))) %>%
+   unnest() %>% View()
Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: length(n) == 1 is not TRUE.
In addition: There were 20 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
```

It seems to be failing on the last mutate. If I run the code without "vald_start" it produces the following result

```
> x_n %>%
+   mutate( vald_end = data %>% map_dbl( ., function(x) max(x$time_cum)),
+           h1 = vald_end - 15*60,
+           index_1 = data %>% map_dbl( ., function(x) which.max(x$time_cum > h1)),
+           index_2 = index_1 - 1) %>%
+   unnest() ->
+ x_r
There were 20 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
> x_r
# A tibble: 10,639 x 10
   meta_event meta_aktivitet meta_subject_id vald_end    h1 index_1 index_2
   <chr>      <chr>          <chr>              <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
 1 001        001            100001              4015  3115     491     490
 2 001        001            100001              4015  3115     491     490
 3 001        001            100001              4015  3115     491     490
 4 001        001            100001              4015  3115     491     490
 5 001        001            100001              4015  3115     491     490
 6 001        001            100001              4015  3115     491     490
 7 001        001            100001              4015  3115     491     490
 8 001        001            100001              4015  3115     491     490
 9 001        001            100001              4015  3115     491     490
10 001        001            100001              4015  3115     491     490
# ... with 10,629 more rows, and 3 more variables: time <chr>,
#   time_cum <dbl>, vo2 <dbl>
> dput(head(x_r))
structure(list(meta_event = c("001", "001", "001", "001", "001", 
"001"), meta_aktivitet = c("001", "001", "001", "001", "001", 
"001"), meta_subject_id = c("100001", "100001", "100001", "100001", 
"100001", "100001"), vald_end = c(4015, 4015, 4015, 4015, 4015, 
4015), h1 = c(3115, 3115, 3115, 3115, 3115, 3115), index_1 = c(491, 
491, 491, 491, 491, 491), index_2 = c(490, 490, 490, 490, 490, 
490), time = c("0:10 min", "0:15 min", "0:20 min", "0:25 min", 
"0:30 min", "0:35 min"), time_cum = c(10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35), 
    vo2 = c(1.665, 2.515, 2.641, 2.677, 2.66, 2.712)), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Can someone point me in the right direction with nth and map_dbl

as per suggestion from @ Moody_Mudskipper, I've tried the following code, without anyluck. I've changed the two strings "time_cum" in the nth function to .$time_cum

```
> x_n %>%
+   mutate( vald_end = data %>% map_dbl( ., function(x) max(x$time_cum)),
+           h1 = vald_end - 15*60,
+           index_1 = data %>% map_dbl( ., function(x) which.max(x$time_cum > h1)),
+           index_2 = index_1 - 1,
+           vald_start = data %>% map_dbl( ., ~ nth( .$time_cum, 
+                                              n = index_1, 
+                                              order_by = .$time_cum))) %>%
+   unnest() %>% View()
Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: length(n) == 1 is not TRUE.
In addition: There were 20 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
```

If I change the code, so I reference use a number insted of index_1, then R provides the expected result. Therefor, I must be doing something wrong, when I reference to the index_1 column.

```
> x_n %>%
+   mutate( vald_end = data %>% map_dbl( ., function(x) max(x$time_cum)),
+           h1 = vald_end - 15*60,
+           index_1 = data %>% map_dbl( ., function(x) which.max(x$time_cum > h1)),
+           index_2 = index_1 - 1,
+           vald_start = data %>% map_dbl( ., ~ nth( .$time_cum, 
+                                              n = 490, 
+                                              order_by = .$time_cum))) -> 
+ x_r
There were 20 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
> x_r
# A tibble: 21 x 9
   meta_event meta_aktivitet meta_subject_id data        vald_end    h1 index_1 index_2 vald_start
   <chr>      <chr>          <chr>           <list>         <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>      <dbl>
 1 001        001            100001          <tibble [5~     4015  3115     491     490       2470
 2 001        001            100002          <tibble [5~     3770  2870     459     458       3575
 3 001        001            100003          <tibble [3~     3840  2940     346     345         NA
 4 001        001            100004          <tibble [5~     3630  2730     456     455       3455
 5 001        001            100005          <tibble [5~     3945  3045     493     492       2460
 6 001        001            100006          <tibble [5~     3860  2960     422     421       3660
 7 001        001            100007          <tibble [4~     3480  2580     356     355         NA
 8 002        001            100001          <tibble [5~     4570  3670     498     497       2450
 9 002        001            100002          <tibble [5~     3755  2855     424     423       3640
10 002        001            100003          <tibble [4~     3560  2660     361     360         NA
# ... with 11 more rows
```

Greetings from Denmark.

Dan Olesen

Comment: Just replace `"time_cum"` by `.$time_cum` ?

Comment: Thank you, for yuor suggestion. When I run it, R throws an error, see question.

Comment: and if you replace the remaining `"time_cum"` by `.$time_cum` ?

Comment: for these cases the help page of the function can really help, you fed a string (`"time_cum"`) to 2 arguments that are explicitly documented to take vectors.

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper, Thank you, for your clarification. When I alter the second "time_cum", R still throws the error. I'm still a beginner, and trying to wrap my head around the syntax.

Comment: no problem we've all been there, but if I use the data you've provided I can't reproduce this error (using the fix I proposed).

Comment: So when you run the code, it runs and provide and result, or does R throw another error?

when I alter the line "vald_s" to this "vald_s = data %>% map_dbl( ., function(x) x$time_cum[491]", where "491 is the actual number frm index_1. Then R provides the expected outcome. So it seems, that my syntax for "n =" is wrong.

Comment: it runs and I have no error. I attribute your first `dput` to x, and then define `x_n`, then run the modified command.

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper, this is change. You are right. When I filter the data, so the nested df only have one row, the code is running. When the nested df have multiple rows, the code does not work. So the nth function seem to take the full column "index_1", insted of the specific row.